# How can i export Event Logs using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-2.0, export-to-excel, powershell-3.0

i'm new to ps scripting , i want to export certain data from event logs. I tried following

```
$Myexcel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$Myexcel.visible = $true
$Myworkbook = $Myexcel.workbooks.add()
$Sheet1 = $Myworkbook.worksheets.item(1)
$Sheet1.name = "summary"
$Sheet1.cells.item(1,1) = 'BootDevice'
$events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{logname="Microsoft-Windows-Storage-Storport/Health"; id=511}

# get the first event raw XML
$event = [xml]$events[0].ToXml()

# display its content
#$event.Event.EventData.Data
$BootDevice=$event.Event.EventData.Data | Where-Object {$_.name -eq "BootDevice"}
write-output $BootDevice
$Sheet1.cells.item(2,1) = $BootDevice
$Sheet1.Columns.AutoFit()
$Myfile = 'E:\tmp\test.xlsx'
$Myworkbook.Saveas($Myfile)
$Myexcel.displayalerts = $true
```

But its giving error

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At line:16 char:1
+ $Sheet1.cells.item(2,1) = $BootDevice
```

And a blank excel is generated.

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: Sounds like a "not configured properly yet"-error - try launching Excel manually (just as a one-time thing) as the user that's supposed to run this script.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks for reply but i tried manually but no data in cell